# How to get a time and Date Separately?

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2005

Table1

Time

```
12/05/2009 08:30:49
12/05/2009 17:00:00
13/05/2009 21:00:00
```

...,

Above Table Both values are same column, Here I want to separate column like Date and Time

Expected Output

```
Date       Time

12/05/2009 08:30:49
12/05/2009 17:00:00
13/05/2009 21:00:00
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can retrieve separate date and time parts like:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DateField,101) as DatePart,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DateField,108) as TimePart
FROM YourTable
```

For more information, see the [CONVERT documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

The code snippet above returns the DataPart and TimePart as a varchar.  If you're interested in retrieving them as a datetime field, try:

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, DateField)) as DatePart,
    DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(D, 0, DateField), DateField) as TimePart
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Hurrah for avoiding varchar!!

Answer (score 3):

The following query returns the date and time respectively for the current system date/time:

SELECT
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8) , GETDATE() , 108) AS [time],
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10) , GETDATE() , 101) AS [date]

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108) as [time],
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 111) as [date]
```

See [this reference for all formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Just a slight modification to pmarflee's answer, because you appear to be wanting the date as dd/mm/yy rather than mm/dd/yy:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8) , GETDATE() , 108) AS [time], CONVERT(VARCHAR(10) , GETDATE() , 103) AS [date]
```