# String manipulation on a converted datetime to varchar t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a smalldatetime field I am converting to varchar (which works fine) now I wanna cut it in the select query to only return the time and not the date.

```
convert(varchar, [DTMON_F]) as mondayFrom
```

This returns "Feb 28 2011 10:30AM" I want to just return "10:30AM"

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620740/how-to-get-a-time-and-date-separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one of the predefined format styles that only contain time parts, such as:

```
convert(varchar, [DTMON_F], 108)
convert(varchar, [DTMON_F], 114)
```

if they give you a suitable output.

Otherwise you can create your own output by concatenating results of various `DATEPART` function calls.

Answer (score 1):

Try `RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, [DTMON_F]), 7)`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Two ways spring to mind

```
select convert(varchar,[DTMON_F],8) as mondayFrom
```

will return 10:30:00 (in 24hr format)

```
select ltrim(right(convert(varchar,[DTMON_F]),7)) as mondayFrom
```

will return 10:30PM

Comment: Note - I've converted in the second example in the same way as you have in your question but you should always set the style if you can so you can be sure of the returned output. Code reads more cleanly too.